# Cannot remove or update a package

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I ran into a problem that I cannot remove or update `masalla-icon-theme` package that I installed from Noobslab ppa using `apt-get`.

The issue is I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and received the package list that is to be upgraded and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> the packages started to upgrade including kernel version to `3.16.0.45` I was running `3.16.0.44` before this and in the end it gets stuck updating `masalla-icon-theme` package, I have RAM counter enabled on my desktop and I can see that it just empties my RAM completely during upgrade of this icon package and the system gets unresponsive can't even move my mouse so I have to do a reset on my computer.

When I try to run: `sudo apt-get remove --purge masalla-icon-theme` it says something like *"try to reinstall a package before a complete removal"*, when I do that the system gets stuck again.

After launching Ubuntu Tweak tool to clean the leftovers it reaches *Old Kernel* option to remove them (I have only `3.16.0.44` there) and then a message pops up saying like *there's a package (masalla...) that needs to be downloaded and additional of 23mb data... will be taken..* and so on, if I click *"continue"* the system gets stuck again. It looks like it's binded to the old kernel somehow, I just can't get it... I just want to remove it completely because of this I can't get other `7` packages enqueued to be upgraded.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

Still not completely sure what was going on, didn't do anything to the system or add any new repos since the last update but after kernel upgrade any time I tried to use `apt-get` or `aptitude` or `dpkg` to install/purge the stated in the OP package the system froze cause of memory lack, even if it was a `.deb` package.

I managed to fix this with [*Y-PPA-Manager*](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8), firstly *disable* the PPA with the causing package (in my case *noobslab/icons*) then `sudo apt-get update` after that start *Y-PPA-Manager* go to *Advanced* and choose *Try to fix all GPG BADSIG errors*. Wait until the process is completed. That's it. In the end:

```
sudo apt-get purge masalla-icon-theme
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then re-enable repository and update the package list and everything works as normal.

Comment: Interesting way;) No, the answer is good.